# Take the path from a string that includes spaces

Tags: javascript, windows

I am trying to take a string such as "turtle util/java test" and and return "util/ java test". This is in windows so spaces in files and folders are allowed.

Currently I have:

```
    let inputLength = line.split(" ").length;//if there's preceding text
    let inputStrip = line.split(" ")[inputLength - 1];
```

However this doesn't work for files/folders with spaces. The issue is that there may be preceding text such as "turtle" before the space that I need to remove from the string.

So an example is I have a string:
"turtle add Documents/Test Settings/file.js"
I want the result to be:
"Documents/Test Settings/file.js"

or I could have:
"Documents/Test Settings/file.js"
and I want the result to be:
"Documents/Test Settings/file.js"

or I could have:
"add Documents/Test Settings/file.js"
 and I want the result to be:
"Documents/Test Settings/file.js"

However I could also have an extreme like:
"word git turtle add catalog field doc/A folder/my worries/going down/turtle/file.txt"

That should become: "doc/A folder/my worries/going down/turtle/file.txt"

The goal is to remove the chars that may be nothing or multiple words, before a filepath, however the file path may contain a space.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand your question with sample input and sample output? I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Show what kind of test cases involved here. Till now from what i understood you can search for /java and remove everything before it. That will do and then make further required changes to get desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. :)

```js
function fetchPath(command) {
  var commandArray = command.split(" ");
  var pathArray = [];
  var i=commandArray.length-1;
  // push the last one which is for sure is a part of the path
  pathArray.push(commandArray[i--]); 

  for(i; i>=0; i--) {
      if(commandArray[i].indexOf('/') > -1) {
        pathArray.unshift(commandArray[i]);
      }
  }

  return pathArray.join(' ');
}


console.log(fetchPath('turtle add Documents/Test Settings/file.js'));
console.log(fetchPath("add Documents/Test Settings/file.js"));
console.log(fetchPath('Documents/Test Settings/file.js'));
console.log(fetchPath('word git turtle add catalog field doc/A folder/my worries/going down/turtle/file.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift()` or `splice()` method.

By using shift() method,

```
var input = "turtle util/java test".split(" ");
input.shift();
input.join(" ");
```

By using splice() method,

```
var input = "turtle util/java test".split(" ");
    input.splice(0, 1);
    input.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let path = 'turtle util/java test';
let firstIndexOfSpace = path.indexOf(' ');

let removedTurtle = path.substring(firstIndexOfSpace);
```

Maybe you should use a guard, because `firstIndexOfSpace` could be `-1`.